# How to use jupyter notebook on sublime text?

Tags: sublimetext3, jupyter-notebook

So there are some plugins packages for Sublime, which lets you use jupyter notebook in sublime.

I went through their instructions but was unable to find any step-by-step instructions on how to get it work.

Like [Helium](https://github.com/pykong/Helium) (previously Hermes)

It's readme guides to use  different functions, but where should I run those code? And which package to import first.

Please help me resolve this.

Comment: It literally has a section called "Usage" in the readme which gives basic instructions on how to get it up and running? If you've tried those steps - perhaps give us more detail on what is going wrong. As for "which package to import first" I don't understand what you are talking about. All you should need is to have Jupyter installed and Hermes installed via Package Control, and then follow the usage instructions and then just code in Python?

Comment: https://github.com/sschuhmann/Helium#usage

Answer (score 5):

I've started to work with the same problem. The commands you are referring can be accessed in the command palette, which can be opened by ctrl+shift+p. In this command palette you can easily type in "Hermes: connect server", but the autocomplete function should help you anyway. ;)